# Excel working with 5 sheets and updating another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I am creating a work sheet for my workers.. Each sheet is a name for that worker so like: James(sheet 1), Elver (Sheet 2), Chris (Sheet 3), John (Sheet 4) and then i have another sheet for another worker say (Mike) that makes things for these builders and are paid for it.

What i would like to do is in A1-A30 i enter something like (8x10) on James sheet (10x20) on Elver sheet etc... on Mikes sheet i want it to automatically go down the rows adding to Mikes sheet from A1 on James sheet or Elvers sheet every time i change a cell from A1-A30 on either of their sheets it automatically add's it to  Mikes sheet

How can i do this i have been trying to figure it out for a week now..Macros? Linking? please help!

I have tried linking, equals etc.. but it's not what im looking for i just want to take any work sheets i make and anytime i enter data in a column it automatically loads it into a specific sheet going down that sheet

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: Version 2203 (Build 15028.20160)

Comment: So that's 365 then?  With the dynamic array handling I am pretty sure you can do it with a formula, let me see if I can put something together.

Answer (score 1):

### A Workbook SheetChange

- Select `Developer > Visual Basic` (<kbd>F11</kbd>). Copy the code to the `ThisWorkbook` module of the correct workbook. Exit the Visual Basic Editor.
- When, in one of the worksheets from the array, a value in the range `A1:A30` is manually changed, this (new) value(s) is written to the first available cell in column `A` of worksheet `Mike`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim Workers As Variant: Workers = Array("James", "Elver", "Chris", "John")
    Const WorkersAddress As String = "A1:A30"
    Const Chief As String = "Mike"
    Const ChiefColumn As String = "A"
    
    If IsError(Application.Match(Sh.Name, Workers, 0)) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim wrg As Range: Set wrg = Intersect(Sh.Range(WorkersAddress), Target)
    If wrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Chief)
    Dim cCell As Range
    Set cCell = cws.Cells(cws.Rows.Count, ChiefColumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim wCell As Range
    
    For Each wCell In wrg.Cells
        cCell.Value = wCell.Value
        Set cCell = cCell.Offset(1)
    Next wCell
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so i did all that and it came back but is putting all data at the bottom of worksheet. which from A3 to A46 i have cells... A3:A39 are all data validation boxes for selecting the building..in which turns =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Config_Builder!$A$2:$F$550,6,0),"") i have this code which gives me the price being paid for the size (A column) it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even think you need VBA as long as your version of Excel supports dynamic arrays.  TEXTJOIN allows concatenating all of the texts in a range or set of ranges, and you can use that to generate an xml document and parse it into an array with FILTERXML.  I have only used two sheets here (James and Elver), but you can add more at will.  You would put this in Mike!A1:

```
=FILTERXML("<xml><x>" & TEXTJOIN("</x><x>", TRUE, James!$A$1:$A$30, Elver!$A$1:$A$30) & "</x></xml>", "//x")
```

Here it is formatted so that it is a little easier to see what's going on:

```
=FILTERXML(
  "<xml><x>" & 
  TEXTJOIN("</x><x>", TRUE, James!$A$1:$A$30, Elver!$A$1:$A$30) & 
  "</x></xml>", 
  "//x"
)
```

First, combine all of the texts using TEXTJOIN, using `</x><x>` as the separator.  You're using this separator so that you can produce a valid xml string to use later.

```
TEXTJOIN("</x><x>", TRUE, James!$A$1:$A$30, Elver!$A$1:$A$30)
```

Wrap that with `"<xml><x>"` and `"</x></xml>"` to finalize the xml string.

```
="<xml><x>" & TEXTJOIN("</x><x>", TRUE, James!$A$1:$A$30, Elver!$A$1:$A$30) & "</x></xml>"
```

and pass the entire generated string to FILTERXML with the selector `//x`.  This will return the text of all `x` nodes in your xml string as an array.  `x` here was selected arbitrarily.  You could use anything.

Here it is working on my machine.  C1 just contains the text so you can see it:[image]

Let me know if that works for you.